# Possible reasons for Socket.Poll method to return false before timeout is reached?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, polling

In the MSDN description of Poll method, with SelectRead option, it is explained when the return value will be true if any of these conditions hold:

> - The Listen method has been called and a connection is pending.
> - Data is available for reading.
> - The connection has been closed, reset, or terminated.

Since Poll is a blocking method, it makes sense that the method will 'wait' for any of these conditions to become true, and if the timeout is reached, return false.

However in my application I am experiencing a 'false' return value before the timeout is reached.

I wonder what can be the reason which led to this?
Is there an accurate way to know?

Comment: You need to show us your application code, without it is unlikely anyone will be able to diagnose the issue....

Comment: I have the following line in my code: `bool hasSomething = mySocket.Poll(pollTime, SelectMode.SelectRead);` with pollTime being 15 seconds (in microseconds). It returns immediately (or maybe after ~1 second - definitely not 15) with value 'false'. The code is from an HTTP client. after sending an HTTP request, the client reads the response byte after byte, and with each byte performs the line I mentioned. Then it runs 'Socket.Receive'). It runs fine usually, but there is one server and one specific URL which causes the mentioned call to 'Poll' to return false (not always, but very frequently).

Comment: Perhaps your socket has KeepAlive enabled and the server was not reachable which caused poll to return because some keepalive packets were dropped?

Comment: Most waits can be interrupted by `Thread.Abort`. Although you'd probably know if you were aborting your thread. Have you tried turning diagnostics on? MSDN says: *This member outputs trace information when you enable network tracing in your application. For more information, see Network Tracing.* What's the value of `pollTime`? `15000000`?